# Adding a UITableViewController.h and .m

Tags: uitableview, tableview

I am a bit desperate, because I tried many days now to add a UITableViewController to one of my TableViews. 
I created the files with - Files - New File - Objective-C Class - Subclass of UITableViewController.

When I give the TableView the Custom Class of my new UITableViewController and run it in the simulator, I always get this message

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];   THREAD1: signal SIGABRT

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong??
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where did you get this funciton `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: forIndexPath` ?
Try this.

```
UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) 
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Comment: Not working. Now it says autorelease is unavailable
ARC forbids explicit message send of autorelease.

Comment: Hope you are a beginner. Just delete the autorelease. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Isn't it obvious! Yes I'm a beginner and therefore I really thank u a lot. It seems to be working. Thanks so much

Comment: Is you found any answers right, then you can accept the answer by clicking the 'right icon' near the answer.

Comment: Just one more - for sure silly question. The TableView in storyboard which now has the class DetailTableViewController, does not show the sections and rows in the simulator anymore. Is this quite normal??

Comment: check whether your 'numberOfSectionsInTableView' not returning 0 and also check if it is calling.

Comment: refer this http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleDrillDown/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: I changed number of sections to 2 and number of rows to 3 in each section. I created the same table in the storyboard. Now it is working. But when I add i.e. a lable or a imageView in a cell in the storyboard, it is not shown when I run the simulator. Maybe I do not understand the concept. Cant I use storyboard anymore with a custom UITableViewController? Do I have to write all in code?